# Android (Pixel 2) doesn't connect to MacBook Pro over USB without restarting computer

Tags: android, macos, adb

I'm finding I need to restart my computer in order for Android to recognize that it's connected to my computer. Sleeping the computer seems to require another restart even after resetting the NVRAM.

When Android won't connect to the computer, plugging the USB cable back in doesn't help. Neither does restarting the phone, changing the USB mode in Developer Settings from "Charging" to "PTP" or the other modes. Nor does killing `adb` and starting it again.

Specs:

- Phone

  - Google Pixel 2
  - Android 8.0.0
- Computer

  - MacBook Pro (Retina, USB Type-A ports)
  - macOS 10.13.1 High Sierra
  - adb 1.0.39 (rev. 3db08f2c6889-android)
- Cable

  - AmazonBasics USB 3.1 Type-A to Type-C

Comment: What happens when you use the C to A cable that came with your phone? Do you have lint in your phone's charge port? I had issues with the usb-c port in my nexus 5x and my pixel (1) and both times it was lint in the charge port.

Comment: Do you have a different computer that you can test the cable out with?

Comment: I've tried it on many different machines and there is not lint in the port.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that it was the cable.  Apparently some USB cables allow only charging but not file transfer.
After trying another cable, my Android File Transfer app detected it right away and I was

Answer (score -10):

You have to enable the Developer Mode and USB Debugging first. See e.g. https://www.bestusefultips.com/enable-developer-mode-on-pixel-2-pixel-2-xl/

After this you should be able to see your device with `adb devices -l` shell command.

Comment: I've got all this set up and sometimes can debug apps on the device but not consistently.